# How to fix Error cannot find module 'core-js/es6'

Tags: mongodb, babeljs

I have been getting an error regardless of what I do. In fact I am building an app with mongoDB as a server using mongoose and babel-watch, but every time I run `babel-watch` I get this error:

> `Error cannot find module 'core-js/es6'`

I have installed and reinstalled `core.js` using `npm install core.js`, however nothing changes. Please help.

These are the dependencies I have installed on my project:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6",
    "cuid": "^2.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "limax": "^1.7.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.9",
    "node-gyp": "^5.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-watch": "^7.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  }
}
```

[Code error seen from terminal after running npm start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpP3V.jpg)

Comment: This might be related to the version of core-js you're using. It may be looking for 'core-js/library/es6' instead of 'core-js/es6'.
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js/v/2.6.8#core-js)

Comment: So what do you suggest that I do?

Comment: Look in the node_modules folder for the package you're looking for to see where they put it. If you provide us with the version your using, we should be able to look at the npm package and give you better direction.

Comment: the version is core.js ^2.6.9

Comment: are you importing core-js/es6 anywhere in your application. you can't do that either import it core-js/es or only import the feature you need. please go through the documentation here if you are still confused. 
https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 2):

For core.js v3.9 import in App.tsx the next line: import "core-js/es";

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using core-js v2.6.9, your path should be `core-js/library/es6` as the example shows you in the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js/v/2.6.9#commonjs).

Comment: So I changed the path in the entry point of the app as suggested, but the same error still reoccurs, I then installed core-js v3.2.1, and still the error remains, I even tried using different paths using recommendations from the documentation but nothing works. And in my `node_modules/core-js` folder there is no `library` folder!

Comment: Can you run `ls -al node_modules/core-js` and show us what IS in there?

Comment: `ls al` command doesn't work.   I just used `ls`<br/>Mode        Length Name<br/>
----        ------ ----<br/>
d-----             es<br/>
d-----             features<br/>
d-----             internals<br/>
d-----              modules<br/>
d-----              proposals<br/>
d-----              scripts<br/>
d-----              stable<br/>
d-----              stage<br/>
d-----              web<br/>
-a----          600 configurator.js<br/>
-a----          106 index.js<br/>
-a----         1064 LICENSE<br/>
-a----        1811 package.json<br/>
-a----         5499 README.md<br/>

Comment: core-js documentation for 3.2.1 indicates that it no longer supports the ability to import a specific ES subset. You can just do `core-js/es` to import all stable ES features.   
https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/README.md#commonjs-api

Comment: I tried that too,  and the same error keeps getting thrown.